# Will the message be delivered again if the subscriber gets the message but the connects fails midway?

Tags: python, mqtt, iot

A message queue stores message until they are consumed When you use a message queue, each incoming message is stored in the queue until it is picked up by a client (often called a consumer). If no client picks up the message, the message remains stuck in the queue and waits to be consumed. In a message queue, it is not possible for a message not to be processed by any client, as it is in MQTT if nobody subscribes to a topic.
What will happen if the subscriber receives the message but is unable to download it due to lack of connection? What measures can be taken to make sure the client gets the message even after this?

Comment: That fully depends on the technologies used, their configuration and how you use them. There is no definite general answer.

Comment: valid question, you can implement two way message, so consumer should give a message back ,then your message queue deletes a message.

Comment: Go read about QOS levels in MQTT

Comment: Also, if there are no subscribers to a topic in MQTT then those messages will (normally) be lost, not queued

Comment: If you need messaging and queuing framework then don't use MQTT, use IBM MQ, ApacheMQ, RabbitMQ, etc.